# Sign Out code is not working with Jquery validations

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

Log out code is not working for WebForms which have Jquery validations. The same log out code is working fine for other forms which don't have any validations. The sign out code is

```
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                Response.Expires = -1500;
                Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
                Session.Clear(); //clear session
                Session.Abandon();//Abandon session
                Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
                Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
```

and Jquery validations code

```
$(function () {
        $("#form1").validationEngine('attach', { promptPosition: "topRight" });

    });
```

These links are added

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ucb.org.br/Scripts/formValidator/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"
        charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.ucb.org.br/Scripts/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js"
        charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and some CSS code is also used in these web forms

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this code in every web form PageLoad event

```
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```